# Android Studio Service runs in the background but doesn't stop after turning it off and on again

Tags: php, android, android-studio, android-layout

I use Service in my application. I am setting up a system that will work continuously in the background. When I exit the application completely (even in the background), my system runs smoothly. However, I'm trying to re-enter the application and activate stopService (). So stopService () remains passive. How can I fix this?

**Note: stopService () works when I try it without exiting the application completely. But when I exit the application completely and re-enter it does not work.**

This is a my MainActivity.java code;

```
btnServiceStart.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        startServices();
    });

    btnServiceStop.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        stopServices();
    });

private void startServices () {
    stopServicePref_DeleteorUpdate();
    startServicePref_Save();
    startService(new Intent(context, Services.class));
    Log.d("bfbdgbdg", "Service started");
}

private void stopServices () {
    startServicePref_DeleteorUpdate();
    stopServicePref_Save();
    stopService(new Intent(context, Services.class));
    Log.d("bfbdgbdg", "Service stoped");
}

private void startServicePref_Save() {
    SharedPreferences prefServisStart_Save = getSharedPreferences("START_SERVICE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edtServisStart_Save = prefServisStart_Save.edit();
    edtServisStart_Save.putBoolean("START_SERVICE", true);
    edtServisStart_Save.apply();
}

private void startServicePref_DeleteorUpdate() {
    SharedPreferences prefServisStart_DeleteorUpdate = getSharedPreferences("START_SERVICE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edtServisStart_deleteorUpdate = prefServisStart_DeleteorUpdate.edit();
    edtServisStart_deleteorUpdate.remove("START_SERVICE");
    edtServisStart_deleteorUpdate.apply();
}

private void stopServicePref_Save() {
    SharedPreferences prefServisStop_Save =getSharedPreferences("STOP_SERVICE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edtServisStop_Save = prefServisStop_Save.edit();
    edtServisStop_Save.putBoolean("STOP_SERVICE", true);
    edtServisStop_Save.apply();
}

private void stopServicePref_DeleteorUpdate() {
    SharedPreferences prefServisStop_DeleteorUpdate = getSharedPreferences("STOP_SERVICE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edtServisStop_DeleteorUpdate = prefServisStop_DeleteorUpdate.edit();
    edtServisStop_DeleteorUpdate.remove("STOP_SERVICE");
    edtServisStop_DeleteorUpdate.apply();
}
```

This is my Service.class codes;

```
 public class Services extends Service {

    Context context = this;
    Handler yardimci = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable;
    boolean getStartServiceData = false;
    boolean getStopServiceData = false;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("sonsonuc", "sonsonuc1");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("sonsonuc", "sonsonuc2");
    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        try {
            startServicePref_Get();
            stopServicePref_Get();
            if(getStartServiceData) {
                statess();
            }
            else if (getStopServiceData){
                notStatess();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        startServicePref_Get();
        stopServicePref_Get();

        if (getStartServiceData) {
            statess();
        }
        else if (getStopServiceData) {
            notStatess();
        }

    }

    private void startServicePref_Get() {
        SharedPreferences prefServisStart = getSharedPreferences("START_SERVICE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        getStartServiceData = prefServisStart.getBoolean("START_SERVICE", false);
        Log.d("getveri", String.valueOf(getStartServiceData));
    }

    private void stopServicePref_Get() {
        SharedPreferences prefServisStop = getSharedPreferences("STOP_SERVICE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        getStopServiceData = prefServisStop.getBoolean("STOP_SERVICE", false);
        Log.d("getveri", String.valueOf(getStopServiceData));
    }

    private void notStatess() {
        yardimci.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void statess() {
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(Servis.this, "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                yardimci.postDelayed(this, 5000);
            }
        };
        yardimci.post(runnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you stop while activity destroys and also why don't you check if it is already running

Comment: @Android Killer My application needs to be running constantly. For him, I do not destroy activity. My application will always check the database. He will do some work according to him. I really need advice on this.